# A way to access context manager variable from class instance in Python?

Tags: python

I would access some variables defined in a context from some classes defined in other modules, like I supersimplify in the following:

in main.py

```
import class_def1
import class_def2

class Starter(object):
    #context manager
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = 'Myfirst'

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.att

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass

with Starter() as f:
    for name in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
        for number in range(2):
            c1 = class_def1.MyClass1()
            print(c1.attr1)
            c2 = class_def2.MyClass2()
            print(c2.attr2)
```

while in class_def1.py:

```
class MyClass1(object):
    global f
    global number
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = ','.join([f,str(number)])
```

and in class_def2.py:

```
class MyClass2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        global f
        global name
        global number
        self.attr2 = ','.join([f,name,str(number)])
```

This code doesn't work, and I would also like to avoid both the use of "global" and input parameters to **init** since I have a lot of variables that I would "pass"...
Maybe I am asking too much. Any suggestion?

**New considerations**

Considering the possibility of using dataclasses as DTO (as suggested by @Niel Godfrey Ponciano), I could create a dataclass this way (or maybe even listing also the other variables and setting a default to zero):

```
@dataclass
class AllInfo:
      f: str

with Starter() as f:
    info = AllInfo(f)
    for name in (a,b,c):
        info.name = name
        for number in range(2):
            info.number = number
            c1 = class_def1.MyClass1(info)
            print(c1.attr1)
            c2 = class_def2.MyClass2(info)
            print(c2.attr2)
```

However, since it is just a matter of storing variables (no methods are required), this is equivalent to:

```
class AllInfo:
      def __init__(self,f):
        self.f = f
```

(the **repr** method that is automatically added to the dataclass is not relevant in my view).

However, in both cases I need to pass the whole info set. Probably not such a problem, since it is a pointer...

Comment: The `__init__` methods should accept the values they need as arguments, not depend on global variables of a particular name. If you have a lot of values, they should probably be bundled up in some sort of container.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, I have lots of values and I could put in a "container", but this "container" will be updated very frequently during the for loops. This is easy to handle when the loops are easy like in my simplified example, but when the nested code becomes much longer and complex in all the parts (not only in the loops) it would be quite hard to check. Moreover I need to pass just a subset of these values to each class.

Comment: Automating the use of global variables is not a scalable solution to the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the `__enter__` method of your context manager `Starter`, as stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#contextmanager.__enter__):

> The value returned by this method is bound to the identifier in the as
> clause of with statements using this context manager.

The value returned is `self.att`:

```
def __enter__(self):
    return self.att  # Returns the string "Myfirst"
```

This means that the value of `f` will be the string "Myfirst". If what you want for `f` is the whole `Starter` instance instead of just the attribute `Starter.att`, then do `return self` instead of `return self.att`.

```
with Starter() as f:  # f will be a string "Myfirst"
```

Now, the next step is to pass that context manager variable (`f` which was from `Starter.att`) along with some iterating values `name` and `number` to your other classes `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`. One standard way of doing this is by performing a [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Types_of_dependency_injection), wherein we would inject the dependencies `f`, `name`, and `value` to the target clients which are `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`. In simpler terms, the design is that `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` depends on `f`, `name`, and `value`.

### Solution 1: Using constructor injection

You mentioned you don't want to pass to init. But this is one of the standard ways of doing this, and also the simplest. Please proceed to solution-2 below if it fits you better,

```
class Starter(object):
    #context manager
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = 'Myfirst'

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.att

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass


class MyClass2(object):
    def __init__(self, f, name, number):
        text_list = [f, name, str(number)]
        self.attr2 = ','.join(text_list)


with Starter() as f:
    for name in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
        for number in range(2):
            # Inject all dependencies to the class
            c2 = MyClass2(f, name, number)
            print(c2.attr2)
```

Output:

```
Myfirst,a,0
Myfirst,a,1
Myfirst,b,0
Myfirst,b,1
Myfirst,c,0
Myfirst,c,1
```

### Solution 2: Using setter injection

If you have a lot of variables but only a selective few of them would be used, this might be applicable. One of the best use cases of this is the [builder design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder).

```
class Starter(object):
    #context manager
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = 'Myfirst'

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.att

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass


class MyClass2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._f = None
        self._name = None
        self._number = None

    # Here, we are using property getters and setters. Of course you can also do it by just directly
    # accessing the variable from the outside, just remove the _ in the name to imply that they are
    # public and not private as it is now).
    @property
    def f(self):
        return self._f

    @f.setter
    def f(self, value):
        self._f = value

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value

    @property
    def number(self):
        return self._number

    @number.setter
    def number(self, value):
        self._number = value

    @property
    def attr2(self):
        # Optionally, you can add checks to filter out null variables in the list
        text_list = [self.f, self.name, str(self.number)]
        return ','.join(text_list)


with Starter() as f:
    for name in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
        for number in range(2):
            c2 = MyClass2()
            # Manually inject each dependency to the class. You can add conditionals to select what
            # should be injected and what shouldn't.
            c2.f = f
            c2.name = name
            c2.number = number
            print(c2.attr2)
```

Output:

- Same as for Solution-1

---

If you have many variables, as suggested by @chepner, you can put them all (or by groups of related data) into its own data structure(s). You can use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) for this purpose (just like `struct` in C/C++) which would act as your [data transfer object (DTO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).

Comment: Thanks. As I said I was looking an alternative to what you proposed as Solution 1. As for Solution 2, re-instantiating the whole class (MyClass2) in every loop would be time consuming, since in every nested loop I need to reinstantiate only some parameters. Moreover, I wouldn't need to consider any attributes as optional, as instead typical for @property usage. Finally, the dataclasses option is indeed interesting, but I don't see any realadvantage with respect to using a standard class and I have to pass the whole parameter set (yes, it is just a pointer)... See changes to my question above.

Comment: Agree, the re-instantiation of MyClass2 on every loop is a bad idea :) But with solution-2 which is somewhat the builder design-pattern, you can actually just instantiate MyClass2 once (outside of the loop, particularly before the loop starts) and then just set/update the properties of the instance upon each iteration when the iterated values move to the next value (thus no need to recreate the instance, just update its properties) so retain inside the loop the `c2.name = name` and the other property-setters.

Answer (score 0):

Python is designed to allow the read of global variables without using the global declaration and If a function needs to modify a variable declared in global scope, it needs to use the global declaration. So the below code should work

```
class MyClass1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = ','.join([f,str(number)])

class MyClass2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr2 = ','.join([f,name,str(number)])

class Starter(object):
    #context manager
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = 'Myfirst'

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.att

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass

with Starter() as f:
    for name in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
        for number in range(2):
            c1 = MyClass1()
            print(c1.attr1)
            c2 = MyClass2()
            print(c2.attr2)

>>> Myfirst,0
    Myfirst,a,0
    Myfirst,1
    Myfirst,a,1
    Myfirst,0
    Myfirst,b,0
    Myfirst,1
    Myfirst,b,1
    Myfirst,0
    Myfirst,c,0
    Myfirst,1
    Myfirst,c,1
```

And if this doesn't help and you really want to access some variable defined in a context in another class you need to pass that variable when initializing. Something like this:

```
class MyClass1(object):
    def __init__(self,f):
        self.attr1 = ','.join([f,str(number)])

class MyClass2(object):
    def __init__(self,f):
        self.attr2 = ','.join([f,name,str(number)])

class Starter(object):
    #context manager
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = 'Myfirst'

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.att

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass

with Starter() as f:
    for name in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
        for number in range(2):
            c1 = MyClass1(f)
            print(c1.attr1)
            c2 = MyClass2(f)
            print(c2.attr2)
```

Comment: This works only when all the code is put in one .py file. For the size of the project and its maintenance on long term, I cannot have just one file.